# How can I groupby multiple properties using a Function in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-functions

I'd like to aggregate across a few properties using a Function. For example, I have a Function where a start and end date is input, and also a Schedule Object Type with "date", "shift_type", "department", and "hours worked" properties.

I'd like my output to be the sum of hours worked for each date/shift type/department combo.

Answer (score 2):

## Creating a data structure for the aggregation

In the current Functions aggregations API, you can only create 2D and 3D aggregations directly from an ObjectSet via the `groupBy` and `segmentBy` functions.

If you want to aggregate on more than two properties (which would be a 4+D aggregation), you have two options:

1. Convert the ObjectSet to a list of Objects (via calling `.allAsync()`), and then write TypeScript logic to convert that list into a data structure that aggregates over the object properties. Note that this may not perform well if you have a large number (thousands or more) of Objects in your Object Set.
2. Add a column to the Object (and the backing dataset) which is a composite key of the columns you want to group on. In your example, this could look like `date.2022-01-01.shift.1200.department.emergency_room`. Then, in your Functions code you could do a `groupBy` on this composite key. Next, you could convert this 2D aggregation into a multi-dimensional aggregation where you split the composite key into its individual parts.

## Displaying this aggregated data in frontend applications

Depending on where you want to use this aggregated data, there may be some additional steps required. Here are some examples:

If you have a Slate or custom application which calls the Function directly and handles the response on the frontend, then you could just return the aggregation as long as it conforms to the [allowed Functions return types.](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/input-output-types/)

If you want to display this data in a table in Workshop (effectively as a Function-backed pivot table), then you will want to use an Object Table with [Function-backed columns.](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/widgets-object-table/#function-backed-columns) You will need an Object which is at the desired level of granularity (where the primary key is the composite key from above, for example). This could be a very simple Object where the only property is this key (and maybe the components of the key, if that is useful for filtering purposes).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can natively in functions, only if you materialize the data into your Functions driver and code the logic manually. However you could create a column at dataset level that you then index into ontology and query that.

In your pipeline (pyspark example)

```
df = df.withColumn("shift_id", F.concat_ws("-", "date", "shift_type", "department"))
```

then in your functions you can aggregate on the shift id:

```
Objects.search()
    .employees()
    .groupBy(e => e.shiftId.topValues())
    .segmentBy(e => e.hoursWorked.topValues())
    .sum()
```